# javascript - Concatenate a two dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say I have an array like this:

```
var myArray = [
                  ['a', 'b'],
                  ['c', 'd']
              ]
```

How do I concatenate this two-dimensional array so I get this as a result:

```
['ab', 'cd']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```
var newArray = myArray.map(function (item) {return item.join('');}); //["ab", "cd"]
```

Comment: I have never used the **Array.prototype.map()** function myself. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/6bw65xj4/1/

```
var tmp = '',
    newArray = [],
    myArray = [
        ['a', 'b'],
        ['c', 'd']
    ];

for(var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++){    
    for(var j=0; j<myArray[i].length; j++) {
       tmp = tmp + myArray[i][j];             
    }
    newArray.push(tmp);
    tmp = ''
}

console.log(newArray);
```